# javascript / jquery - firefox textarea does not seem to register value

Tags: javascript, firefox, textarea

I have simple routine to show tips in the textarea to the users.  If the user focuses on the textarea and there is no user input, the script clears the tips.  If the area is blurred without user inputs, the area shows the the tips.

This seems to work fine in IE and chrome, but firefox 3.6 does not seem to work every time.

Click the textarea to focus, the textarea clears the text

Don't type anything and click outside to unfocus the textarea, the tip will show.

Click the textarea again to focus, but the text won't disappear.

Click outside to unfocus

Click the textarea again to focus, this time the text area will clear the text.

Any tip or insight to correct this behavior for firefox 3.6?

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/3nEA6/)

TIA

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>            
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
<div style="text-align:center">
   <textarea id="btext"  onfocus="clearOnFocus()" onblur="showtip()">
Enter text
</textarea><br>
</div>
 <!-- end page -->
<script language="javascript">

function clearOnFocus () {
  //alert ('test');

  var patt=/Enter text/g;
  var result=patt.test($('#btext').val());
  if (result) {
    $('#btext').val('');
  }
}//end of clear

function showtip () {
  var textinput = $('#btext').val();

  if (textinput == '') {

  var btips = 'Enter text';

  $('#btext').val(btips);
    }
}//end of showtip

</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems to work fine in Firefox 7.0.1.

Comment: @Pointy Confirmed. Also, Spaces/newlines within the `<textarea>` tag are parsed, so remove the beginning and trailing newlines. Then, replace the RegExp by `/^Enter text$/`, so that `"Enter text now"` doesn't match.

Comment: it works as intended in IE6+ & Chrome, but not FF3.6.  It is not a big problem, but I am just trying to understand and confirm the behavior in FF3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a regular expression to test that the value is something other than just whitespace. You can also test against the default value to see if anything has beeen entered. That way your script is independent of the value of the textarea.

```
<textarea onfocus="
  if (this.value == this.defaultValue) 
    this.value = '';
"
onblur="if (/^\s*$/.test(this.value))
  this.value = this.defaultValue
">Enter text</textarea>
```

Comment: What about using `tab` to focus on the textarea?

Comment: @RobG, thanks, I tried your method, it does not work at all in FF3.6, onfocus does not illicit a response. It works fine for other browsers.

Comment: It works for me in Firefox 3.5 on both Windows and Mac OS (it works in IE 6 too). You need to be careful with Firefox, it doesn't automatically reset control values when you re-load the page. Click in the address bar and press enter, don't just use reload or ctrl+R.

Comment: Thanks RobG, the tip for the address bar reload works, I did not know about the differences.  Can I pass 'this' into a function instead of using this method inline?

Comment: NVM RobG, answered my own question.